# I am trying to raise a POST request to generate bearer token through RestClient in rails, but getting 403 Forbidden as status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rest-client

```
require 'base64'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

key="**************************"
secret="****************************************"
str="#{key}"+":"+"#{secret}"
encoded_str= Base64.encode64(str).delete("\n")
encoded_str = "Basic "+"#{encoded_str}"
response=RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', headers: {'Authorization': encoded_str, 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"},body: {'grant_type': "client_credentials"})
puts response.code
```

## consumer key and secret are correct

## encoded_str is correct, verified through postman.

Comment: check this link https://twittercommunity.com/t/repeated-requests-to-oauth2-token-eventually-returns-403/12006

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Also instead of RestClient, I used HTTParty.

Answer (score 0):

Actually twitter do have some limitations on the amount of times you can negotiate a token – it helps to discourage widely distributed client-side use cases of this form of auth. You need to check the documentation in detail for rate limits.